# How to get list of users requesting permissions for a file/folder using Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to get list of users requesting permission for a file/folder using Google Drive API.

I have seen API to grant permission to an email address using the API but couldn't find any endpoint to get list of users requesting access to a file/folder.

Ideally I want to fetch get all the users requesting permissions for my shared folders and approve/deny them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with current [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference), but you could use [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference) as a workaround:

1. [list email](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) by labels (add filter to those emails requesting access)
2. parse it
3. grant access to users you want with [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference)

Good luck,